# Print all the Spring beans that are loaded

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to print all the spring beans that are loaded on startup?I am using Spring 2.0.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Yes, get ahold of `ApplicationContext` and call `.getBeanDefinitionNames()`

You can get the context by:

- implementing `ApplicationContextAware`
- injecting it with `@Inject` / `@Autowired` (after 2.5)
- use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(..)`

Related: You can also detect each bean's registration by registering a `BeanPostprocessor` bean. It will be notified for each bean.

Comment: The reason to implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface is because Spring framework give it the *chance* to access the application context. You should place it in the `@Configuration` class for the intended application context.

Comment: A related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829258/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-instantiated-beans-from-spring

Comment: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() does not show the beans which are registered without BeanDefinition instance. You will not be able to list singleton beans which are registered manually. ex-:) you can not list environment, systemProperties,systemEnvironment beans. However these beans are available in the container. You can autowire them using @Auwired Environment env etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54863282/1840774

Comment: Neither `getBeanDefinitionNames()` nor `getSingletonNames()` works with `@ConditionalOnProperty` beans. `BeanPostprocessor` works with all beans I've got, which is more robust.

Answer (score 76):

```
public class PrintBeans {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void printBeans() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
    }
}
```

Comment: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() does not show the beans which are registered without BeanDefinition instance. You will not be able to list singleton beans which are registered manually. ex-:) you can not list environment, systemProperties,systemEnvironment beans. However these beans are available in the container. You can autowire them using @Auwired Environment env etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54863282/1840774

Comment: Does this work in a OSGi environment?

Answer (score 28):

With Spring Boot and the actuator starter

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you can check the endpoint `/beans`

Comment: Question was for Spring 2.0, *not* Spring Boot.

Comment: @TMN The question is 11 years old.

Answer (score 23):

Print all bean names and its classes:

```
package com.javahash.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value="key", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {

        String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

        for (String beanName : beanNames) {

            System.out.println(beanName + " : " + applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass().toString());
        }

        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

Comment: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() does not show the beans which are registered without BeanDefinition instance. You will not be able to list singleton beans which are registered manually. ex-:) you can not list environment, systemProperties,systemEnvironment beans. However these beans are available in the container. You can autowire them using @Auwired Environment env etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54863282/1840774

Answer (score 14):

**applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()** does **not** show the beans which are registered **without** BeanDefinition instance.

```
package io.velu.core;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Core {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Core.class);
        String[] singletonNames = context.getDefaultListableBeanFactory().getSingletonNames();
        for (String singleton : singletonNames) {
            System.out.println(singleton);
        }       
    }
}
```

### Console Output

```
environment
systemProperties
systemEnvironment
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
messageSource
applicationEventMulticaster
lifecycleProcessor
```

As you can see in the output, **environment, systemProperties, systemEnvironment** beans will **not** be shown using **context.getBeanDefinitionNames()** method.

### Spring Boot

For spring boot web applications, all the beans can be listed using the below endpoint.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/list")
class ExportController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @GetMapping("/beans")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    String[] registeredBeans() {
        return printBeans();
    }

    private String[] printBeans() {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        if (autowireCapableBeanFactory instanceof SingletonBeanRegistry) {
            String[] singletonNames = ((SingletonBeanRegistry) autowireCapableBeanFactory).getSingletonNames();
            for (String singleton : singletonNames) {
                System.out.println(singleton);
            }
            return singletonNames;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
[
   "autoConfigurationReport",
   "springApplicationArguments",
   "springBootBanner",
   "springBootLoggingSystem",
   "environment",
   "systemProperties",
   "systemEnvironment",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry",
   "propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer",
   "org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.store",
   "preserveErrorControllerTargetClassPostProcessor",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor",
   "org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor",
   "org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor",
   "methodValidationPostProcessor",
   "embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor",
   "errorPageRegistrarBeanPostProcessor",
   "messageSource",
   "applicationEventMulticaster",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat",
   "tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebSocketConfiguration",
   "websocketContainerCustomizer",
   "spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration",
   "localeCharsetMappingsCustomizer",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration",
   "serverProperties",
   "duplicateServerPropertiesDetector",
   "spring.resources-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$DefaultErrorViewResolverConfiguration",
   "conventionErrorViewResolver",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration",
   "errorPageCustomizer",
   "servletContext",
   "contextParameters",
   "contextAttributes",
   "spring.mvc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcProperties",
   "spring.http.multipart-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration",
   "multipartConfigElement",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration",
   "dispatcherServlet",
   "dispatcherServletRegistration",
   "requestContextFilter",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration",
   "hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
   "httpPutFormContentFilter",
   "characterEncodingFilter",
   "org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor",
   "org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory",
   "reportGeneratorApplication",
   "exportController",
   "exportService",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration",
   "spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties",
   "standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration",
   "jsonComponentModule",
   "jacksonObjectMapperBuilder",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration",
   "jacksonObjectMapper",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration",
   "defaultValidator",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration",
   "error",
   "beanNameViewResolver",
   "errorAttributes",
   "basicErrorController",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter",
   "mvcContentNegotiationManager",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration",
   "stringHttpMessageConverter",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration",
   "mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration",
   "messageConverters",
   "mvcConversionService",
   "mvcValidator",
   "requestMappingHandlerAdapter",
   "mvcResourceUrlProvider",
   "requestMappingHandlerMapping",
   "mvcPathMatcher",
   "mvcUrlPathHelper",
   "viewControllerHandlerMapping",
   "beanNameHandlerMapping",
   "resourceHandlerMapping",
   "defaultServletHandlerMapping",
   "mvcUriComponentsContributor",
   "httpRequestHandlerAdapter",
   "simpleControllerHandlerAdapter",
   "handlerExceptionResolver",
   "mvcViewResolver",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter$FaviconConfiguration",
   "faviconRequestHandler",
   "faviconHandlerMapping",
   "defaultViewResolver",
   "viewResolver",
   "welcomePageHandlerMapping",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration",
   "objectNamingStrategy",
   "mbeanServer",
   "mbeanExporter",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration",
   "springApplicationAdminRegistrar",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration",
   "spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration",
   "multipartResolver",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfiguration",
   "restTemplateBuilder",
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration",
   "spring.devtools-org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsProperties",
   "org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration",
   "fileSystemWatcherFactory",
   "classPathRestartStrategy",
   "classPathFileSystemWatcher",
   "hateoasObjenesisCacheDisabler",
   "org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$LiveReloadConfiguration$LiveReloadServerConfiguration",
   "org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$LiveReloadConfiguration",
   "optionalLiveReloadServer",
   "org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration",
   "lifecycleProcessor"
]
```

Comment: To note that `context` is not closed in your code and should be created inside a try-with-resouces statement. `try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ())`

Answer (score 8):

You could try calling

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(Object.class)
```

Or turn on debug logging for `org.springframework`. (In spring boot, that's using a parameter `--logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`)

Comment: `ListableBeanFactory` is an interface. Where would one get an instance of a class extending that interface in order to execute the method `getBeansOfType` or any other method in the interface? I see that `ApplicationContext` extends it, but your example doesn't show how to acquire one of those.

Comment: You can just add a field `@Autowired ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory` and you'll get one (the implementation type shouldn't matter)

Comment: I found the bean registrations  at:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: debug

This shows beans like this:
2021-08-23T17:30:36.547Z DEBUG 5255 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'apacheHttpClientBuilder'

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to print all the bean names from the spring application context:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

/***********************************************************************************************************
 * Java File: MainApplication.java
 * Description: Main class to run the application.
 * 
 ***********************************************************************************************************/

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);

    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    logger.info("**************** START: Total Bean Objects: {} ******************", context.getBeanDefinitionCount());

    Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames())
    .forEach(beanName -> {
        logger.info("{}) Bean Name: {} ", counter.incrementAndGet(), beanName);
    });

    logger.info("**************** END: Total Bean: {} ******************", context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
}

}


Sample Output:

2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:18] - **************** START: Total Bean Objects: 564 ****************** 
...........................
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:22] - 460) Bean Name: mvcPathMatcher  
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:22] - 461) Bean Name: mvcUrlPathHelper  
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:22] - 462) Bean Name: viewControllerHandlerMapping  
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:22] - 463) Bean Name: beanNameHandlerMapping  
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:22] - 464) Bean Name: resourceHandlerMapping 
...........................
2019-11-27 20:08:02.821 INFO  [main] [c.c.a.MainApplication:25] - **************** END: Total Bean: 564 ******************
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `spring-boot-starter-actuator` you can easily access all bean.

Here is the setup process:

1. **Add dependency into gradle**:

Add bellow into gradle file:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

2. **Enable security on application.properties**:

Add `management.security.enabled=false` into your application.property file

1. **call /beans endpoint**:

   After that setup spring will enable some metrics related endpoints.
   One of its endpoint is **/beans**
   After calling this endpoints it will provide a json file that contains all of your bean including it's dependency and scope.

Here is an example json file:

```
[{"context":"application:8442","parent":null,"beans":[{"bean":"beanName","aliases":[],"scope":"singleton","type":"packageName$$4b46c703","resource":"null","dependencies":["environment","beanName1","beanName2"]},{"bean":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory","aliases":[],"scope":"singleton","type":"org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory","resource":"null","dependencies":[]}]
```

For more info visit bellow links:

- [Building a RESTful Web Service with Spring Boot Actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/)
- [Spring Boot Actuator: Health check, Auditing, Metrics gathering](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjH-KapmY_eAhVJpo8KHVMKCpsQFjAEegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.callicoder.com%2Fspring-boot-actuator%2F&usg=AOvVaw2DV1OFpkfzAAQUF_RfPVyC)
- [Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Hope this will help you. Thanks :)

Comment: spring != spring-boot