# spring boot constructor parameter could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on spring boot app with tutorial. I did everything like guy from tutorial but still have problem with some constructor:(

The error is:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.wewtorek.shop.controllers.AdminController required a bean of type 'com.wewtorek.shop.models.data.PageRepository' that could not be found.

Code is:

```
package com.wewtorek.shop.controllers;
import com.wewtorek.shop.models.data.Page;
import com.wewtorek.shop.models.data.PageRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    private PageRepository pageRepository;


    public AdminController(PageRepository pageRepository) {
        this.pageRepository = pageRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String admin(Model model) {

        List<Page> pages = pageRepository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("pages", pages);

        return "admin";
    }
}
```

PageRepository:

```
package com.wewtorek.shop.models.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Integer> {
}
```

Application:

```
package com.wewtorek.shop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ShopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShopApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the pageRepository and application class as well?

Comment: Please add your repository interface (with the package name!) and the class that bootstraps the things (the one with `@SpringBootApplication`) on it.

Comment: You do have a datasource configured?

Answer (score 1):

First :

**@Repository** is missing

```
@Repository
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Integer> {
}
```

Doc : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories

You dont have to create an constructor in controller :
It should be something like this :

```
    public class AdminController{

    @Autowired
    private PageRepository pageRepository;


    --- Code ---
    }
```

**@Autowired** instanciate a service, you dont have to build it

BUT you have to put **@Repository** or **@Service** to use **@Autowired**

I take this example from my school project :

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ZEH.png)

In my LoanService i call another server but u can replace it by u'r repository

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zelhS.png)

And last tips i promise :D, a complete NoSQL school project i did
https://github.com/juju630/ClientServeurNoSQL

( sry not native )

Comment: indeed i forgot to add @Repository but it still does not work:(

Comment: Well , in second time you should remove this constructor and use @Autowired, recommend to take a look from baeldung doc : )

Comment: @Repository is not required in Spring Boot applications. Beans with a singular constructor are automatically attempted for autowiring for a few years now.

Comment: Autowired inherently means field injection which is not recommended by Spring. OP used constructor injection which ideally should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your project, this is going to be hard to give a definitive solution.

What is happening is when spring tries to create the bean `AdminController` it can not find a unique bean as the dependency `PageRepository`.

A few things to look at to try to solve this

Is the bean `JpaRepository<Page, Integer>` annotated correctly for spring to pick it up and create an instance?

Is the bean `JpaRepository<Page, Integer>` being scanned by spring?

What is your package structure? this can be very important for the default scanning of spring beans.

To investigate you could add a default constructor to allow it to ignore the dependency, then debug out all beans on startup of your app using the answers
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348937/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded-spring-boot)

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you want more details on the possible causes, feel free to comment.