# Print Bean Scope Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to print the scope of spring bean? I am using beans defined in multiple jar files. I am able to print the bean names of all the beans loaded , but i am trying print the scope as well.

EDIT: I loaded the names of all spring beans using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded). I want to print the bean scope as well (prototype , singleton , request , session)

Comment: This is unclear, what is your use-case? What did you try?

Comment: @Tunaki , edited and added more details.

Comment: It is right in doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#isPrototype-java.lang.String- ; you can check every bean name's scope

Comment: You can get the names, and you can use the `BeanFactory` to get the `BeanDefinition`s, but this won't necessarily be very helpful. When you declare a proxy scoped bean, you actually get two bean definitions.

Comment: Thanks dk14 & Sotirios!