# EnumTranslator bean is not injected (is null)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, inject

`RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class of **Spring Data REST** has method `enumTranslator()`:

```java
@Bean
public EnumTranslator enumTranslator() {
  return new EnumTranslator(resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor());
}
```

that (I expect) registers an '**enumTranslator**' Bean.

But when I try to use it in my component then it isn't injected and always is `null`:

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private final EnumTranslator enumTranslator; 

    public MyComponent(EnumTranslator enumTranslator) {
        this.enumTranslator = enumTranslator;
    }

    public void someMethod() {             
        // enumTranslator -> null
    }
}
```

Could somebody explain why does this happens and how to correct inject such beans?

**UPDATE**

I've figured out - I tried to implement a class (Spring converter) that isn't managed by Spring ))

Thanks everybody who tried to help me!

Comment: What you describe should work, so there's probably something missing from your description. Are you sure that it's Spring that's instantiating the `MyComponent`?

Comment: (Run it in a debugger, put a breakpoint in the constructor, and look at the stack to see what's calling the `MyComponent(EnumTranslator)` constructor)

Comment: Thanks @slim ! I've found the reason - check my update.. )

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`  bean was not loaded in the Spring container.
Try for example to import it with `@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)` from a `Configuration` class.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/install-chapter.html) :

> **2.4 Configuring Spring Data REST**
>
> ...
>
> You can either import this class into your existing configuration
> using an @Import annotation or you can subclass it and override any of
> the configureXXX methods to add your own configuration to that of
> Spring Data REST.

Comment: Since Spring 4.3, if there's only one constructor, `@Autowired` is implicit and not required.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I kept the habit to specify it anyway. I edited.

Comment: I don't refer to autowiring it but to importing the bean. You can check it by displaying all loaded Spring beans. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx ! I've found the reason - check my update )