# Bean Names are being returned in String Format, Call methods or use variables of such bean

Tags: java, spring

I am bringing the beans that are being loaded in container with the help of below function. I got this from this SO question: [Getting all beans in context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded).

```
Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames())
```

this is returning me bean names as a list as shown below

> [helloWorld, helloWorld2, helloRandomCountry, beforeAfterPrint]

for the beans configuration file snapshot as below

```
  <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.springspp.HelloWorld">
    <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id = "helloWorld2" class = "com.springspp.HelloWorld">
    <property name = "message" value = "Hello Hello World!"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="helloRandomCountry" 
    class="com.springspp.countries.HelloJapan"/>
  <bean id = "beforeAfterPrint" class = 
     "com.springspp.BeforeAfterPrint">
  </bean>
```

Now I'm having a list of these beans with me and they are in **STRING Format**. If I want to call any method in that class or use any variable that is being defined in that class how could I do that. I checked for linked and relative questions in Stack Overflow but I didn't find any answers.

Typical use case is as follows. I want to find out the variable

> country

from below class that is configured in metadata file as helloRandomCountry as its bean name as shown above

```
    class HelloJapan implements Countries{
        String country="Japan";
        private String thisClassString="Hello this is Japan";
        public void displayString() {
            System.out.println(thisClassString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Accessing a bean directly through the spring context is usually **not** needed.  Instead, allow spring to inject the beans into the classes which depend on them.

Comment: Use `@Autowire`.

Answer (score 0):

You really wouldn't want to do this in production code, but I am assuming you are simply learning.

You can call [context.getBean("beanName")](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-). That will return a raw Object. So you would need to cast it the correct object. There are other methods that you can attempt to use, but since you are using the same class type for them, you might run into issues.

Comment: Yes I do agree that is not acceptable in production environment. But my question is I am having lets assume 3 classes implemented of same interface that is countries.  and 2 bean definitions in which could be of any class type. Now bringing in those beans and I want to call the instance methods of those beans?? . If beans are 10 for say, for each bean I want to iterate over it. how can this be done please help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected bean like this

```
HelloJapan helloJapan = context.getBeansOfType(HelloJapan.class).get("helloRandomCountry");
```

And then call the method you want on it.