# Scheduler as dependency in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I have two maven module 'client' and 'scheduler'. 'scheduler' module consists of code with Scheduler and runs each minute. When I run 'scheduler' module, it is working fine and scheduler executes each minute. Now, when I add it as a dependency in 'client' module, scheduler never runs.

Comment: Probably you have to enable scheduling in your main application and do a component scan for the package of the scheduler.

Comment: @chuckskull Why don't you add this as the answer?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It's been two years since I last touched spring boot. So, memory is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot needs to know two things to run the scheduler. i.e The bean of the scheduler and config for enabling scheduling.

So, you need to add `@EnableScheduling` annotation to enable the schedulers and you need to register the scheduler bean in the spring context. For that, you can use

```
@ComponentScan (basePackages= {'current project package', 'scheduler package'}
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {'current project package', 'scheduler package'}
```

Comment: still scheduler is not executable.

Comment: Also, if I were to create a constructor or Autowire any classes in scheduler package, do I have to create a bean passing each constructors in client module?

Comment: @Smritimool you can check the list of all beans registered in the context and see if the required is there or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039278/8084588

Also, make sure that the dependency is properly added in the classpath.

Comment: @Smritimool Please also post your annotations used in the runner class.