# How to get DataSource bean from config in the Junit5

Tags: spring, junit5, spring5

Dears,

I have created a junit5 test case ( UserDaoTests.java) but I am not able to get DataSource Bean defined in the spring configuration file (data.xml).

**Project Structure:**

test cases are defined in test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/tests package, UserDaoTests.java class.

[image]

**data.xml**

 configuration file for junit. I have defined datasource bean in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.tests">
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/config/jdbc.properties" />

    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

**jdbc.properties:**

```
jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = TESTD01)))
jdbc.password=1234
jdbc.username=offerTest
```

**Junit test(UserDaoTests.java)**

```
    package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.tests;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import com.offers.DAO.UserDAO;

@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/config/data.xml",
        "classpath:com/offers/config/offerDAO-context.xml", 
        "classpath:com/offers/config/offerService-context.xml" })



public class UserDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;
    
    private static  DataSource dataSource; 
    
    private  JdbcTemplate jdbc;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserDaoTests() {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/config/data.xml");
        this.dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        if ( dataSource == null) {
            System.out.println("DataSource is null");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DataSource is not null!!!!  ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

I would also like to clarify that I am using static DataSource because I need to use @BeforeAll, which require static fields only.

I have tested for non static Data Source as well but result is still the same.

--Update----

I removed `<beans profile="dev">` tag from data.xml config file and it's working fine. But I don't understand why it's not working with profile.

--- Update 2 ( Update on on Bhushan's answer) -----

**UserDaoTests - updated code**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
//Add all required depency xml
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/config/data.xml",
        "classpath:com/offers/config/offerDAO-context.xml", 
        "classpath:com/offers/config/offerService-context.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class UserDaoTests {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(dataSource);
        // Assertions.assertNotNull(jdbc);
    }
}
```

**Error Stacktrace:**

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:109)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:283)
    at com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.tests.UserDaoTests.testCreateUser(UserDaoTests.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: I think, you need to add bean definitions, i mean .xml files even in test resources folder too.

Comment: You cannot inject into static fields.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot.  I am working to modify my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are creating multipe application context, one is creating with **@ContextConfiguration** and another one with **FileSystemXmlApplicationContext**, so avoid FileSystemXmlApplicationContext and update your code following

> ```
> @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
> //Add all required depency xml
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
>         "classpath:test/com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/config/data.xml",
>         "classpath:com/offers/config/offerDAO-context.xml", 
>         "classpath:com/offers/config/offerService-context.xml" })
> @ActiveProfiles("dev")
> public class UserDaoTests {
>     @Autowired
>     private UserDAO userDao;
>     
>     @Autowired
>     private DataSource dataSource; 
>     
>     @Autowired
>     private  JdbcTemplate jdbc;
>     
>     
>   @Test
>     public void testCreateUser() {
>            Assertions.assertNotNull(dataSource);
>            Assertions.assertNotNull(jdbc);
>     }
> }
> ```

Also avoid **@BeforeAll** as its coupled with static memory, and ours Beans are managed by spring so can't go with it, instead of it you can you for **@BeforeEach** and if you want perform some logic witch you want run only once for all test cases so you can do **hack** something like

```
private AtomicBoolean executed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@BeforeEach
public void runOnce() {
    if(!executed.getAndSet(true)) { 
        // write you logic which you want will run only once for all test cases
    }
}
```

Comment: THe `ContextConfiguration` is actually useless here as there is no `@ExtendsWith` indicating that it should use the dedicated spring extension.

Comment: right, I missed that, updated code, Thank @M.Deinum

Comment: @BhushanUniyal Thanks for your reply. But it's still not working. I will update the error and updated code in the question.

Comment: try to printout all spring beans and debug if required beans there
 @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public void printBeans() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
    }
more ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded/54863282#54863282ean to bu

Comment: I got null pointer exception on applicationContext object itself.

Comment: Than issue in xml path in annotations, could you try with full path using file: instead of classpath, so we can dubug the issue