# How can I use my own ceated jar dependency in other spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jar, aop

I have created a jar file for Automatic logging using spring boot and AOP, now I have added the jar in other spring boot project, and jar is added in maven dependency, but it is not logging anything.

I am taking, base package name from property files, and accessing it using xml configuration, in my AOP project(jar that i created).

here is the AOP code

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAdvice {    
    private LogDetails logDetails = new LogDetails();
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAdvice.class);  
    public Object logger(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        Object[] array = pjp.getArgs();
        Object object = pjp.proceed();
        Instant end = Instant.now();
        long timeTaken = Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
        logDetails.setServiceName(pjp.getSignature().getName());
        logDetails.setTimeStamp(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS").format(new Date(timeTaken)));
        logDetails.setMessage(pjp.getTarget().getClass().toString() + ", Method:-> " + pjp.getSignature().getName()
                + ", Arguments:-> " + mapper.writeValueAsString(array));        
            log.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(logDetails));        
        return object;
    }
}
```

This is the xml file, in which i am getting base package from properties file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <bean id="LoggingAdvice"
        class="com.cerner.generic.logger.advice.LoggingAdvice"></bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="logallaspect" ref="LoggingAdvice">
            <!-- @Around -->
            <aop:pointcut id="logAllMethodsAround"
                expression="within(${base.package}..*)" />
            <aop:around method="logger"
                pointcut-ref="logAllMethodsAround" />
            <!-- @After-Throwing -->
            <aop:after-throwing
                pointcut-ref="logAllMethodsAround" throwing="e"
                method="afterThrowing" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

And this is how added this jar in, other project, basically it should produce logs, but it is not producing.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cerner.generic</groupId>
    <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>          
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed if `LoggingAdvice` bean is getting created ?

Comment: yes logging advice is working fine alone, but after including it as jar in other application, it is not logging

Comment: After adding as a dependency , confirm if the `LoggingAdvice` bean is getting registered to the application context.

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded

Comment: No it is not getting registerd

Comment: That is what you have to solve first . Your need to register the `LoggingAdvice` as a bean with the application context .  Either through `ComponentScan` or other means

Comment: okay, i am trying

Comment: i am not able to register it as bean. I added componentScanner at main class. then it produced this bean. (loggingCodecCustomizer)

Comment: could you please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . `loggingCodecCustomizer` is not the `LoggingAspect`

Comment: Its done, Thankyou. After creating bean, It is working

Comment: Great ! You may close this question with your findings

Comment: Sure......! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I Registered the LoggingAdvice bean as suggested by R.G in above comments.
Here is the little modification that i did.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages =
  {"basePackageOfPatientApplication", "basePackageOfLoggingAdvice"}
)
public class PatientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PatientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And it worked for me!!